# Please explain the correct usage of the words according to the situation

Tags: vocabulary

Please explain the meaning and usage of the following words:

1. Bereft of
2. Denuded of
3. Deprived of

I searched some sentences and concluded that in some sentences they all can be used alternatively.

Please explain with sentences.

Answer (score 1):

"Denuded of" implies removal of an outer layer, e.g. clothing.

"By the time they were rescued from the river, they had been denuded of their clothes."

"Having been neglected for years, the house's roof had been denuded of its tiles by the elements".

"Bereft of" implies something has been lost that's usually abstract such as a feeling.

"His mother's returning illness left him bereft of hope."

"Deprived of" means something has been denied to someone, perhaps by a person or events e.g.

"The fire deprived the family of their newly built house."

"The defendant's death before the trial deprived her of the chance of justice".